# Prove that $G/N$ is a nilpotent group of class at most $c$ iff $C_{c+1} \subset N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $C_{i}=C_{i}(G)$ be the higher commutator subgroups of a group $G$. Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Prove that $G/N$ is a nilpotent group of class at most $c$ iff $C_{c+1} \subset N$.

I try to use this fact: If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then we have $C_{i}(G/N)=C_{i}(G)N/N$. Can anyone help me complete the proof?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: By "higher commutator subgroup" you mean the $\;i$- th element of the lower central series? :$$\gamma_1:=G\ge \gamma_2:=[G:G]\ge\gamma_3:=[\gamma_2,G]\ge\ldots\ge \gamma_i:=[\gamma_{i-1},G]\ge\ldots$$

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: @chuyenvien94 I think you already gave the answer yourself! For $\gamma_{i}(G/N)=\gamma_{i}(G)N/N$. And hence $\gamma_{i}(G/N)=\bar{1}$ iff $\gamma_{i}(G)N=N$ iff $\gamma_{i}(G) \subseteq N$. So the nilpotency of a quotient is reflected by the fact that some member of the lower central series is a subset of the normal subgroup in question.

Comment: @Nicky Hekster: Thank you very much.

Comment: @chuyenvien94 You are welcome!